# Flexcube WebService

Tags: web-services, weblogic, soap-client, gateway

Updated Question: I try to Test FLEXCUBE in Weblogic, Firstly I create properties file and build ear file. After that I upload FCUBS ear file in Weblogic, and this is screenshot from weblogic

[image]

I open FCJNeoWeb and I see a Login screen Like that

[image]

Firstly, I create an user and password in FLEXCUBE and I login successfuly, and I see this screen
[image]

Untill now, all of things looks good. Hovewer, when I click one of the operaion in this page it give me null like that 
[image]

**Trace files :** 
[Enter this link for Tracefile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gv3e1ys4w5xrpr6/gtwy_ora_24096.trc?dl=0) 
Is there anyone have any idea about this operation ?

LOG File of RADTOOL :

[image]

The Screen of RADTOOL
[image]

Comment: i hope all Data sources are created.. please post application log as well

Comment: Hi vital. I could'nt find the log file of FCUBSApp, if you want I can share trace file

Comment: yes please share..also will suggest u to post your queries on this groups on Linked In for more info on Flexcube https://www.linkedin.com/grp/home?gid=1892457 and https://www.linkedin.com/grp/home?gid=3739001

Comment: Hi, I share trace file link in the end of my question which is under Trace files header, I upload the file in dropbox. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi vishal I have error when we try to login radtool and I add logs file in question please can you look it ?

Comment: RAD Data Sources are created right? try to login with default user.. RADTOOL/RADTOOL.. also any pop up msg its showing when trying to login?

Comment: Hi Vishal, I add the screen shot of RADTOOL with userid and password RADTOOL/RADTOOL  but i give wrong USERIDA and PASSWORD

Comment: I solve RADtool :))) it is opened, but I will need your help again

Comment: hi vital, the problem of login page in FCUBS is solved but when I enter Function id --> GWDEXSYS it gives me this error :  "Function rights not available.  Error code : SM-00198" and how can I set permission to users ?

Comment: your user have ALLROLES? also in smtb_menu there is record for GWDEXSYS. JS and UIXML files have full access rights in deployment area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very specific to Flexcube web service header value parts and not the generic values.
I have worked on this Flexcube web service before and i can tell you an values based on my experience.

**Source-->** System name which invoking this service(e.g EXTSYS,FCDB,etc) and same details of  calling system must be maintained at flexcube level as well.

**UBSCOMP-->** by default its values is ***FCUBS***

**User id-->** Flexcube application login user id. You can request for creation of userid for accessing this service

**Branch -->** Is the branch code(eg. 000, 101, etc) where your user have access to perform operations

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your response, I deploy gateway service and FCUBAPP ear to flexcube, I just dont understand that what you mean "same details of calling system must be maintained at flexcube level as well" how can I do it ?

Comment: Same details means.. suppose your are trying to access web service from FCDB then you need to maintain  same external system details in FLEXCUBE as well.. here is sample xml for you..for querying account--><FCUBS_HEADER>
  <SOURCE>FCDB</SOURCE> 
  <UBSCOMP>FCUBS</UBSCOMP> 
  <USERID>TESTUSER3</USERID> 
  <BRANCH>000</BRANCH> 
  <SERVICE>FCUBSAccService</SERVICE> 
  <OPERATION>QueryCustAcc</OPERATION> 
  </FCUBS_HEADER>
- <FCUBS_BODY>
- <Cust-Account-IO>
  <BRN>000</BRN> 
  <ACC>2000000111</ACC> 
  </Cust-Account-IO>
  </FCUBS_BODY>
  </QUERYCUSTACC_IOFS_REQ>

Comment: In above comment you can see.. Source as --> FCDB means my invoking system is FCDB. you can get details of external system in **gwtm_ext_sys_master** table... Userid--> TESTUSER3 is user which i have created in Flexcube. Also if you have flexcube application up then you can add/view external system from Function id --> **GWDEXSYS** which can communicate with Flexcube

Comment: Hi thanks , could I ask another question again   My question is when I deploy FCUBSApp on weblogic, I tried to test EJB/FCJLogin  adminserver as a testpoint,  but I got these errors                                                                                         "Failure using JNDI to lookup the EJB home FCUBSApp/ejb/FCJLoginHome on the server AdminServer. "  and this           " While trying to lookup 'FCUBSApp.ejb/FCJLoginHome' didn't find subcontext 'FCUBSApp'. Resolved ''"     Have you ever seen any errors like that or do you have any idea about that

Comment: Sorry for this i don't have much idea.. even its hard to tell with out application debug file.. You will get clear description of your error in server.out file at location (e.g D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\NewDomain\servers\AdminServer\logs)

Comment: Hi, when I type source, branch etc on flexcube it give me this error : Exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: Invalid URL. Please check the input WSDL URL

Comment: I hope you have checked [Recompilation required] Check box while creating web service EAR

Comment: Actually, when I create ear I didnt check [Recompilation required] Check box, and now I check it but ear doesn't recompile and give me this error :

Comment: :/Gateway/WS/FCUBSICService/src/com/ofss/fcubs/gw/ws/FCUBSICServiceImpl.java does not exist

Comment: yes.. you can generate required impl.java and wsdl file from RADTOOL for this service..and place those files in required location

Comment: Hi, I try to run Gateway web service on weblogic but it give me this error :FCUBSAccServiceImpl [callEJB(String p_reqMsg,String g_gwLog)] 16_JUL 19:26:13:391->Calling GWEJBClient.callRemoteEJB

FCUBSAccServiceImpl [checkDetailsQueryIO(CHECKDETAILSQUERYIOFSREQ requestMsg)] 16_JUL 19:26:13:407->EXCEPTION

java.rmi.RemoteException: Error in ejbCreate:; nested exception is:
        javax.ejb.CreateException
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.sendReceive(ServerRequest.java:205)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:347)

Comment: at com.iflex.fcubs.gw.ejb.GWEJB_GW_EJB_Bean_jg7dym_EOImpl_1036_WLStub.processMsg(Unknown Source)
        at com.iflex.fcubs.gwservices.ejb.GWEJBClient.callRemoteEJB(GWEJBClient.java:172)
        at com.ofss.fcubs.gw.ws.types.FCUBSAccServiceImpl.callEJB(Unknown Source)
        at com.ofss.fcubs.gw.ws.types.FCUBSAccServiceImpl.checkDetailsQueryIO(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

Comment: getting this error after creating EAR file with recompilation checked ?

Comment: Hi  Vishal, when I check recomilation it give me this error : 07 23 10:23:15 GatewayBuild   [DEBUG]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '/DESTTEMPDIR/20150723__1023/Gateway/GW/GW_EJB/src/FCJInsulation.properties' does not exist

Comment: at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:636)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(FileUtils.java:586)

Comment: i know its difficult to create EAR for Flexcube web service.. but sorry if EAR created with recompilation then only it will work.. need to generate required file from RADTOOL.. even its difficult for me to tell with out log file why its failing.. check with some experience person from your team.. who can help you on this.

Comment: Hi could I ask another question to you because few people have experince about flexcube, as I said before I try to run a gateway webservice, for this, do I have to create Oracle FLEXCUBE Function ID ? and I f I have to , how can I create it, should I use rad tool for it ?

Comment: U don't need to create any function ids just make sure which ever operation u wanted to do from service.. that operationhas an entry in gwtm_Operation_master table.that is what the reason i asked to generate impl file and use it to create webservice ear..with recompilation checked

Comment: Hi Vishal can I ask another question ?  i send my request but now I got this error : have you ever seen this error : ECODE>GW-ROUT0003</ECODE>
            <EDESC>No data found for the service, operation and source combination</EDESC>

Comment: Check in gwtm_operation_master... there is no data for service and operation.. make sure all INC file related to service are compiled.. or u can make manual entry in it

Comment: select * from gwtm_operation_master where service_name = 'FCUBSCustomerService';

Comment: I use this query because my service name is FCUBSCustomer Service  I see result like that Service_Name FCUBSCustomerService , OperationCode = CreateCustomer, Module_Code = ST. Reply_Reqd = Y, Full_Screen_XSD = NULL, input_only_XSD = null

Comment: and PKEY_RES_XSD : ST-CreateCustomer-Res-PK-MSG.xsd,FC_FUNCTION_ID = STDCIF, ACTION = new

Comment: Can you paste ELB and Web service logs... from that i can tell you what is the issue.